# React Native mobile app suddenly stopped building

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

The compiler shows this error. How can I handle it?

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

[image: error]

What I've tried:

- ./gradlew clean
- chmod +x gradlew
- npx react-native start --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

Can you run [React Native Doctor](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/11/18/react-native-doctor)?

```
npx @react-native-community/cli doctor
```

This will help us to understand if the problem is related to your app or your computer setup.

Comment: I can't manage to run the doctor :( I have an error "Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module". But when I try to install it, I also get an error.

Comment: what's your node version? `node --version`

Right now the officially supported version for react-native is 18+